# SQL clause vs expression terms

Tags: sql

I had a discussion with a teammate on the topic whether the terms `clause` and `expression` can be used interchangeably. For example, is it correct/common to call a variable that stands for an `expression` `a=b` (e.g. that participates in a statement `SELECT * WHERE expression`) a clause?

### Edit

It would be useful is someone could give precise definitions of what `clause`, `expression` and `statement` are in SQL world.

Comment: @jarlh could you elaborate? isn't an expression also a clause but not the other way around?

Comment: it's `statement` vs `expression` (search for `javaScript`)

Comment: @metadings not quite. There can't be any statements (that are not expressions) inside a `WHERE clause` from what I understand. So what is a clause then? From the documentation on postgres for example, all the clauses have a name (`WHERE clause` etc.). So a clause is something that has a keyword like `WHERE` + an expression?

Comment: You can make a `statement` to an `expression`, by re-using a `SELECT expression` in a `SELECT JOIN statement`, e.g. `SELECT * FROM objekt JOIN (SELECT * FROM text)`

Comment: @metadings I think you mixed things up, expression is a part of a statement, not the other way around. And the question is not about SQL statements, its about clauses and expressions.

Comment: Like a javaScript `function` statement you also have a `var fn = function` expression;  
in SQL you have a `SELECT` statement, which you may use as an expression.

Comment: The `clause` here maybe an `expression`, but is usually just the value, `4`, `literal text`, `byte[]`, a `TableName` or a `ColumnName`... You should rename them to `fragment` or `section`!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In SQL Terms, "clause" is usually used to refer to a *section* of a statement, usually introduced by the keyword it's named after - e.g. a typical `SELECT` statement would be composed of a `SELECT` clause, a `FROM` clause and a `WHERE` clause. *Within* the `FROM` clause, *some* people may refer to `JOIN` clauses and `ON` clauses. However, this is by no means 100% accepted usage.

When it comes to "statement" and "expression", it's fairly standard usage - an expression is something that *produces a value*. In most languages, this is understood, further, to be something that produces a *scalar* value. In SQL, this is slightly modified because when you encounter an expression when working with a row set, the expression will produce one scalar value *per row* (or per group or partition, if grouping or partitioning are involved and it's in the relevant location).

Finally, a statement is a complete "something" that your database engine can understand and produce results for. It doesn't produce a *value* but it may produce a result set. You can't just send a `FROM` clause to the database - it has to be part of a larger statement, such as the `SELECT` statement I mentioned in my first paragraph.

Comment: thanks for clearing things up. So its ok to refer to `a=b` (whatever it is) that comes after `WHERE` a clause?

Comment: @iggy - I would usually refer to the `WHERE` clause as everything from `WHERE` until the `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` or another major keyword. If the `WHERE` clause is `WHERE a=b OR c = d` I would refer to it in its entirety as the `WHERE` clause, but would refer to `a=b`, by itself, as a predicate (a specific *type* of expression that produces a boolean value - but since some variants of SQL don't have a boolean type, they're not the same as most expressions)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO, expression evaluates to something may be a `boolean value` or `string` or `number` where as a clause forms a rule for the data to satisfy and only then the record forms part of the result.

```
select * from TABLE where /*clause 1*/ field1 = field2 
and /*clause 2*/field3 = /*expression*/ field1 + field2
```

In the above select statement

> first clause forms a rule which is field1 should be equal to field2
>
> Second clause form a rule which is field3 should be equal to the result of the > expression `field1 + field2`

**UPDATE**

There are various clauses in SQL like `from`, `where`, `order by`, `group by` and `having`. `from` clause tells from which table to read and order by tells how to arrange the result. Clauses control from where data to be read, what data be formed as part of the select statement and how the data to be presented.

Expression on the other hand evaluate to a value of some datatype.

A Statement, is a structured query build with the clauses.

Comment: actually your `clause 1` is exactly what I asked for, you call it a `clause` but you say that the answer is NO

Comment: but that is not an expression

Comment: so you say that `a=b` which evaluates to ` boolean` (ok probably this is algebra so its more like a relation) is a clause?

Comment: but what do you mean by `expression could be part of it`? Whatever is inside the `WHERE` clause "returns" a boolean (it defines algebraic relations more strictly) so it must be an expression from your first sentence.

Comment: You are right, in saying that a `clause` maybe just a `value`, but it also maybe an `expression`. 
`SELECT * FROM objekt
JOIN (SELECT * FROM text) USING (sha512)
WHERE sha512=?` is the `statement`.

Comment: `AND` is not a "clause" but an (conjunction) operator.