# Sum with join giving wrong value

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, left-join

I have a query that does strange behavior to my output.

My tables look something like this:

**Table Leistungen**
Columns Abrechnungsnummer(varchar), KST_Leistung(varchar), ZZ_Euro(money), GG_Euro(money), Rezept_ID(varchar), Rechnungsart(varchar)

**Table Leistungen_pos**
Columns Rezept_ID(varchar), US(varchar),

The tables use the "Rezept_ID" for connection. The output has to be grouped by Abrechnungsnummer and KST_Leistung. Each SUM is dependet on the US-Field (1 and 21 together, 2 and 22 and so on..).
The problem is, the 2nd join change the output from my first SUM from the 1st join.

```
SELECT dbo.Leistungen.Abrechnungsnummer,
CASE WHEN (dbo.Leistungen.KST_Leistung = '') THEN 'ohne' ELSE dbo.Leistungen.KST_Leistung END AS Kostenstellen,
CASE WHEN (SUM(lposK_US1.GG_Euro) IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE SUM(lposK_US1.GG_Euro) END AS SummeGesamtKasse19,
CASE WHEN (SUM(lposK_US2.GG_Euro) IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE SUM(lposK_US2.GG_Euro) END AS SummeGesamtKasse7, 
CASE WHEN (SUM(lposK_US3.GG_Euro) IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE SUM(lposK_US3.GG_Euro) END AS SummeGesamtKasse16,
CASE WHEN (SUM(lposK_US4.GG_Euro) IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE SUM(lposK_US4.GG_Euro) END AS SummeGesamtKasse5
FROM dbo.Leistungen
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Leistungen_Pos AS lposK_US1 ON lposK_US1.Rezept_ID = dbo.Leistungen.Rezept_ID AND dbo.Leistungen.Rechnungsart = 'K' AND lposK_US1.US IN ('1', '21')
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Leistungen_Pos AS lposK_US2 ON lposK_US2.Rezept_ID = dbo.Leistungen.Rezept_ID AND dbo.Leistungen.Rechnungsart = 'K' AND lposK_US2.US IN ('2', '22')
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Leistungen_Pos AS lposK_US3 ON lposK_US3.Rezept_ID = dbo.Leistungen.Rezept_ID AND dbo.Leistungen.Rechnungsart = 'K' AND lposK_US3.US IN ('3', '23')
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Leistungen_Pos AS lposK_US4 ON lposK_US4.Rezept_ID = dbo.Leistungen.Rezept_ID AND dbo.Leistungen.Rechnungsart = 'K' AND lposK_US4.US IN ('4', '24')
WHERE Abrechnungsnummer = '5432200101'
GROUP BY dbo.Leistungen.Abrechnungsnummer, dbo.Leistungen.KST_Leistung
```

My problem is, the first row of my query have a value of, i.e. 29181,52.. that value is wrong!

[image: wrong]

If I deactivate the 2nd JOIN with 2 and 22, I got the right value (29131,12).
That is the value I got, if I do a simple select on the right fields without any joins.

[image: right]

I can't explain why this SQL adds a small value on my very first row, when I use a second join and treat it like an independent result.
It has to be a syntax-error, because I checked the data and it is reasonable.

Hopefully, someone can help me solve this problem.

Here are some samples

[image: sample]

As soon as I add a value more for US=2, it adds the value 20.
How can this happen, if I restrict the join for 2 and 22?

the result looks like this:

[image: wrong result]

You can see

[image: here]

it puts the value 7 in the same row. Instead it has to be in his own row and NULL for the 2nd 20-value.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify the problem! ([mcve].)

Comment: Guessing you have a many to one relationship, and so when you `JOIN` you `SUM` the same value(s) 2 or more times.

Comment: Without sample data which reproduces the issue its going to be very hard to assist you.

Comment: Are there any duplicate values in the field `lposK_US2.Rezept_ID`?

Comment: Please don't post data as images, use formatted text.

Comment: Because `Rezept_ID` is repeated twice for value `11614619` in table `lposK_US2`, you have a *one to many* relationship. This means that the result of the join will replicate the data of the table `dbo.Leistungen`, because it is joined twice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to join the same supplementary table multiple times to the main table, and the supplementary table has a many to one relationship.

Here's an easier way to get the same result. First, summarise the desired sums using a `CASE` <s>statement</s> expression in a CTE. Then you will have exactly one line per `Rezept_ID`.

Then join the CTE back to the main table.

```
;WITH summarise AS (
SELECT
 a.Rezept_ID,
 SUM(CASE WHEN a.US IN ('1','21') THEN a.GG_Euro ELSE 0 END) AS SummeGesamtKasse19,
 SUM(CASE WHEN a.US IN ('2','22') THEN a.GG_Euro ELSE 0 END) AS SummeGesamtKasse7,
 SUM(CASE WHEN a.US IN ('3','23') THEN a.GG_Euro ELSE 0 END) AS SummeGesamtKasse16,
 SUM(CASE WHEN a.US IN ('4','24') THEN a.GG_Euro ELSE 0 END) AS SummeGesamtKasse5
FROM
 dbo.Leistungen_Pos a
WHERE
 a.US IN ('1','21','2','22','3','23','4','24')
GROUP BY
 a.Rezept_ID
)
SELECT
 l.Abrechnungsnummer,
 l.Rezept_ID,
 CASE WHEN l.KST_Leistun = '' THEN 'ohne' ELSE KST_Leistun END AS Kostenstellen, 
 s.SummeGesamtKasse19,
 s.SummeGesamtKasse7,
 s.SummeGesamtKasse16,
 s.SummeGesamtKasse5
FROM
 dbo.Leistungen l
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
 summarise as s
  ON
   l.Rezept_ID = s.Rezept_ID
WHERE
 l.Abrechnungsnummer = '5432200101'
```

Comment: case *expression* not *statement* :)

Comment: @DaleK not that first time I've made that mistake. :) Indeed, there's even a [question on it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34132046/8471799).